# C# Version and .NET Framework Version?

Tags: c#, frameworks

I am confused with both the C# version and .NET framework version. In other words, I want to know the relationship with C# version and .NET framework. E.g: which is C# version in .NET framework 3.0?

Answer (score 23):

I am not sure what your actual question is, but if it is what are the current versions..

[C#: 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336745.aspx)
[.NET Framework: 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx)

You might also want to take a look at [this breakdown chart](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/fernando/archive/2009/01/11/net-framework-release-map.aspx).  It provides the Framework, language and CLR relations.
[image]

Comment: The current framework version is 3.5 SP1 - for example including the ADO.NET Entity Framework not present in version 3.5.

Comment: Yes, if you follow the link to the framework it will provide the current version.  Is SP1 now a mandatory update in windows?

Comment: thanks for good post!it's very help to me

Comment: The chart is wrong, though. The C# that shipped with .NET 1.1 was C# 1.2. Crazy, but there it is...

Comment: Also (for the OP) - note that C# 3 can be used with .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0, especially if you use something like LINQBridge.

Comment: @Marc I didn't know that C# 1.2 shipped with 1.1, wierd.

Answer (score 4):

C# 1.0 - Managed Code

C# 2.0 - Generics, Nullable Types, Anonymous Delegates, Partial Classes / Methods

C# 3.0 - LINQ, Lambda Expressions, Implicit Variable Typing, Streamlined Object Initialization

// Related? somewhat perhaps

Answer (score 1):

.net 2 C# 2

.net 3 C# 2

.net 3.5 C# 3

Comment: While this **is** the timeline for the versions' releases, they are not so strictly bound to each other. You can use C#3 with .NET 2, 3, & 3.5. At the same time, you could use C# 2 with .NET 2, 3, and, albeit a very limited subset (unless you want to write ugly code), 3.5