# Target Framework and C# version queries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

1. Is the C# version related in any way to the targeted framework?
2. How do I know which C# version I'm using?
3. How can I change the C# version I'm using?
4. What would I lose by going from .NET Framework 4 Client Profile to .NET Framework 2?
5. Does the selected framework restrict the range of OS versions the compiled program is able to run on?

Comment: I very well feel that this would map to 5 different (duplicate) question here on SO ! !

Comment: I searched before, but didn't really find the answers to my questions. Would you mind providing some links then?

Comment: About C# versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688441/c-sharp-version-and-net-framework-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: well, broadly; later frameworks tend to ship with later compilers; .NET included C# 2, .NET 3.5 included C# 3, .NET 4.0 for C# 4 and .NET 4.5 for C# 5

2: you can have multiple versions on your computer, and this is *in part* dictated by which IDE you are using, or whether you are using the command line. At the command line, `csc` will tell you which version it is

3: various options: use a different IDE; use a different version of csc from a different framework version; use csc with the `/langversion` toggle; set the "Language Version" in the "Advanced..." dialog in project properties (Visual Studio)

4: LINQ, WCF, WPF, etc - lots of bugfixes and additional framework methods / tools

5: the computer must have the required framework, sure enough...